# счётчик по клику

Tags: javascript, jquery

на странице стоит N количество счётчиков, при клике на + увеличивает значение на 1 или при клике на - уменьшает на 1. Значение не должно быть меньше 0. Проблема у меня что не знаю как можно сделать это для несколько элементов на странице, как это можно реализовать?

```
html:
<div class="counter">
<button class='btn__arrow plus'>+</button>
<input type="number" value="0">
<button class='btn__arrow nimus'>+</button>
</div>

<div class="counter">
<button class='btn__arrow plus'>+</button>
<input type="number" value="0">
<button class='btn__arrow nimus'>+</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример

```js
function counterFunction(count) {

  var plus = count.querySelector('.plus');
  var minus = count.querySelector('.minus');
  var number = count.querySelector('.number');
  var numberValue = parseFloat(number.value, 10);

  minus.addEventListener('click', function() {

    if (numberValue === 0) {
      return;
    };

    numberValue--;
    number.value = numberValue;
  });

  plus.addEventListener('click', function() {
    numberValue++;
    number.value = numberValue;
  });

}

var counts = document.querySelectorAll('.counter');

counts.forEach(counterFunction);
```

```css
.counter {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="counter">
  <button type="button" class="minus">-</button>
  <input type="number" class="number" value="1" placeholder="1">
  <button type="button" class="plus">+</button>
</div>
<div class="counter">
  <button type="button" class="minus">-</button>
  <input type="text" class="number" value="1" placeholder="1">
  <button type="button" class="plus">+</button>
</div>
```

Comment: подскажите как сделать чтобы меньше 0 нельзя было значение опустить

Comment: В функции где -- в самое начало добавляете проверку. If(numberValue ==0) return;

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="counter">
    <button class="plus">+</button>
    <input type="text" value="0">
    <button class="minus">-</button>
</div>
<div class="counter">
    <button class="plus">+</button>
    <input type="text" value="0">
    <button class="minus">-</button>
</div>
<script>
    var countBlocks = document.querySelectorAll(".counter");

    for(var i = 0; i < countBlocks.length; i++) {
        countBlocks[i].onclick = function() {
            var plusBtn = this.querySelector(".plus");
            var minusBtn = this.querySelector('.minus');
            var textField = this.querySelector('input');
            var textFieldVal = +textField.value;

            plusBtn.onclick = function() {
                textField.value = textFieldVal + 1;
            }
            minusBtn.onclick = function() {
                textField.value = textFieldVal - 1;
            }
        }
    }   
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы не считать меньше 0, ставим проверку на обработчик клика кнопки "-":

```
minusBtn.onclick = function() {
    if(textFieldVal == 0)
        return false;
    else                        
        textField.value = textFieldVal - 1;
}
```